# How to get the title of an particular element using x and y coordinates?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, appium

1.I need to get the title without using locator element. I have pasted the below inspected information for getting the particular title.

2.I need to get the title using x and y location.

3.I don't how to get the text using x and y coordinates of particular web element using java.

4. I have pasted the below information, Which I have got from Appium inspector.

> ```
> Info:
> content-desc: Cedar Key Class of 2015 Heading
> location: {40, 684}
> size: {620, 52}
> ```

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
driver.findElementByName("Cedar Key Class of 2015 Heading").getText();
```

Comment: can you add some explanation?

Comment: @AdrianCidAlmaguer , I need to get the above title using location:  {40, 684} ie X and Y coordinates. Without using the locator, I need to get the title. Is there any way to grab the title using x and y coordinates?